# What am I doing wrong here while manipulating the DOM?

Tags: javascript

I want to see the input type and the text "This is some text" on the page

```
const ui = document.createElement('ul');
const item = document.createElement('li');
item.innerHTML = "<input> This is some text";
ui.appendChild(item);
```

Comment: You haven't actually appended `ui` to the document...

Comment: You are creating an `ul` element on the fly as well. Were are you appending it to the current document?

Comment: rofl we ALL caught that one.

Answer (score 4):

You additionally need to actually append `ui` to the DOM itself.

In the following example, I append it to `<body>`, which I get with **[`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)**. Note that this returns a **[`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of elements, so you need to access the first result with `[0]`.

```js
const ui = document.createElement('ul');
const item = document.createElement('li');
const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
item.innerHTML = "<input> This is some text";
ui.appendChild(item);
body.appendChild(ui);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing something like:

```
document.body.appendChild(ui)
```

```js
const ui = document.createElement('ul');
const item = document.createElement('li');
item.innerHTML = "<input> This is some text";
ui.appendChild(item);

document.body.appendChild(ui)
```

So far you've created the elements but they're not inserted into the DOM.